# Async Await code. Why it is not working?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, c#-5.0

Simple code to check URL/website name is valid or not.
This code(sync code) works perfect. When I comment sync code and uncomment the `async` code, the code is not working fine. What is the wrong in my `async` programming?

```
class Program
{
    static StringBuilder urlStatus = new StringBuilder("");
    //public static async Task<string> GetHeadersAsync(string url)     //Async Code
    public static string GetHeadersAsync(string url)    ////Sync Code
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        request.Method = "HEAD";
        try
        {
            //using (var response = await request.GetResponseAsync() as HttpWebResponse)   //Async Code
            using (var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse)     ////Sync Code
            {
                if (response != null && response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return "HTTP_OK";
                return "Error";
            }
        }
        catch (WebException ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return ex.ToString();
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string lineData;
        //content of URLList.txt
        //http://www.oracle.com
        //http://www.oracletest.com
        //http://www.cnn.com
        //http://www.cnntest.com
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("URLList.txt"))
        {
            while ((lineData = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                var urlRetStatus = GetHeadersAsync(lineData);
                urlStatus.Append(lineData + " " + urlRetStatus.ToString() + System.Environment.NewLine);
            }
        }
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"ErrorURL.txt", urlStatus.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to specify which error are you receiving, otherwise it's hard for anyone to help you. I guess it would indicate that you're using async method incorrectly.

Comment: @ Isantipov, I am not getting error. But it writes "System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]" I am not getting the intended results also with Async code enabled.

Comment: @EricSmith That's the result of calling `ToString` on a `Task<string>` instead of the actual result. See my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call an `async` method you get back a task that represents the asynchronous operation. To extract the actual result out of that task you use the `await` keyword:

```
Task<string> task = GetHeadersAsync(lineData);
string result = await task;
```

In your case you're calling that method from `Main` which can't be an `async` method and can't use `await` so you need to use the `Task.Result` property:

```
Task<string> task = GetHeadersAsync(lineData);
string result = task.Result;
```

Keep in mind that this will block the calling thread until the `async` operation is completed so this is not recommended.

Comment: It is important to STRESS that `Task.Result` can AND WILL create a deadlock when you block on the UI thread, whilst `SynchronizationContext.Current` points to a context that uses the UI thread's message pump.